# Defer Messages and Specify Queue

Tags: rebus

I have been playing around with Rebus and RabbitMQ, and came across a scenario I cannot seem to get working.

I have a couple of queues; `queue1` & `queue2` and they take the same class/message type. Now, Rebus seems to prefer different message types per queue, this is not an option for me right now, so i use the advanced routing `bus.Advanced.Routing.Send("queue1", Message)`

I would like to utilise the `bus.defer` functionality but am unsure how to combine them both. I know I might need to introduce a `waiting` queue as an external timeout manager (which I have yet to get working too, but thats for another day)

Has anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

#### How to send the message

As you have probably discovered, when you `bus.Defer`, Rebus will use the endpoint mappings to look up the destination queue from the type of the message being deferred (which is analogous to `bus.Send`/`bus.SendLocal`, in that it has an accompanying `bus.DeferLocal` too, which always sends to the sender's own input queue).

What is missing, is something analogous to `bus.Advanced.Routing.Send`, but fortunately it is pretty easy to emulate a combination of `bus.Defer` and an explicitly routed message but setting the `rbs2-deferred-recipient` header on a message:

```
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    {Headers.DeferredRecipient, "destination-queue"}
};

var delay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

await bus.DeferLocal(delay, yourMessage, headers);
```

#### How to configure the timeout manager

You can use Rebus' internal timeout manager by configuring some kind of timeout persistence – e.g. by pulling in Rebus.SqlServer and using SQL Server to store timeouts like so:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Timeouts(t => t.StoreInSqlServer(...))
    .Start();
```

Another option is to install a Rebus endpoint as a dedicated timeout manager, which simply uses the same configuration as can be seen above, and then all other endpoints do this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Timeouts(t => t.UseExternalTimeoutManager("timeouts"))
    .Start();
```

assuming that your timeout manager uses the `timeouts` queue.

---

#### Update relevant from Rebus 5

Rebus 5 (which is currently available as a prerelease package on Nuget.org) has builtin support for deferring messages to an explicitly specified destination queue.

It can be done like this:

```
var delay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

await bus.Advanced.Routing.Defer("dest-queue", delay, message);
```

which will simply carry out the steps mentioned above underneath the covers.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have done as you say using a rabbitMQ queue for the external timeout manager, but i cannot get it working. Does the timeout manager endpoint have the `timeouts` queue as its consumer queue and the timeouts queue? Also, does the endpoint that picks up the deferred message from the timeouts need to have `UseExternalTimeoutManager` configured?

Comment: Try and read the documentation here: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Timeout-Manager – maybe that will make it more clear